# How to get data worked by all Users and Individual Users? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a tool to track chat handled by Agents. So I as an Admin should be able to view chats for all Agents. I wrote a code, but code only gives data for agents.

I should also be able to see data for All Agents from the dropdown list to select.

Here is the Code I wrote

1. Calendar Filters along with DropDown list for all Agents

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("TeamPerformance", "ChatLog", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <br />
                                <h3 class="text-center">Team<span> Performance</span></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold;">Start Date Time</label>
                                <input type="datetime" name="start" id="datepickerStart" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold;">End Date Time</label>
                                <input type="datetime" name="end" id="datepickerEnd" class="form-control" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold;">User</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("username",new SelectList(ViewBag.userN, "Username", "Username"), "All", new { @class="form-control"})
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Controller

```
public ActionResult TeamPerformance(DateTime start, DateTime end, string username)
        {
            var st = start;
            var en = end;
            var us = username;

            if (us != null )
            {
                using (Db db = new Db())
                {
                    ViewBag.teamchatCount = db.Chats
            .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end && x.Username == us).ToList().Count();

                    var totalChat = db.Chats
            .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end && x.Username == us).ToList();

                    return View(totalChat);
                }
            }


            else
            {
                using (Db db = new Db())
                {
                    //var uName = User.Identity.Name;

                    ViewBag.teamchatCount = db.Chats
                .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end).ToList().Count();

                    var totalChat = db.Chats
                .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end).ToList();

                    //ViewBag.START = st;
                    //ViewBag.END = en;

                    return View(totalChat);
                }
            }

        }
```

So, when I select a date, I should be able to select agent name from drowdown and view data, which is working. But code should also show me All Agent data when I keep the default as "All" in drop down.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, kind of guessing at this, but assuming your `username` drop down has "All" as an option, I would code it like this:

```
public ActionResult TeamPerformance(DateTime start, DateTime end, string username)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        var baseQuery = db.Chats
            .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start 
                   && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end);
        
        if (username != null)
        {
            // Filter for user
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(u => u.UserName == username);
        }
        
        var totalChat = baseQuery.ToList();
        ViewBag.teamchatCount = totalChat.Count();
        
        return View(totalChat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried above code, but still same results. For All it shows 0 results, and shows result when select a user. I want to show data for user and if select All it should show data for all users.

Comment: My bad, compare username to null if it is not selected. See edit. You should be able to easily debug this - set a break point at the first line of controller. Click submit without selecting a user. What is the value of username? Should be null. That is what you want to compare to. If data is still empty, then you will want to view the generated SQL and run that manually against your database.